# unchange the object order

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

We put the object1 first,then put the object2,and put the object3 finally on the canvas.
It's mean that object1 is on the bottom,and object3 is on the top.

When we want to change the object2 url or do sth on it,we remove  it and add the new object2 after.

But now object2 is on the top.
I know some method like sendToBack(),moveTo(),....etc,can change the order of the object2.

There is no clue about fix the object order.
Is there some method already existed  or other statement can apply?
If not,is the only way that we change their order again and again by applying method as above after  change the object layer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [insertAt()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#insertAt) to insert the object at given index.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  fill: 'red',
});
var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  left: 30,
  top: 30,
  fill: 'green',
});
var rect3 = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  fill: 'black',
});
var rect4 = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  left: 30,
  top: 30,
  fill: 'yellow',
});
canvas.add(rect1,rect2,rect3);
function alter(){
 var index = canvas.getObjects().indexOf(rect2);
 //canvas.remove(rect2);
 canvas.insertAt(rect4, index,true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<button onclick="alter()">Alter</button>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```